# How to query a map on array on firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using flutter for mobile development and I need to query an map on array in firestore.

My code :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("/notes")
            .where({
              "semester 1"
            }, arrayContains: [
              {"ec321ece"}
            ], isNotEqualTo: [
              {"value321ece"}
            ])
          
            .snapshots()
            .listen((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
                 
                 print("${element.data()}");

                }));
```

[image: my firestore image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use array contains with maps, in the way that you are trying.  There are a couple of options:

### Array of Maps and Array of Keys

Have your existing `semester 1` array with the maps, but also add a second array called `Semester 1 IDs` and store only the values (as strings) that you want to search for.

### Sub-collections

Using a `semesters` sub-collection of your `notes` document will give you greater flexibility in your searching.  Also, if your `notes` document grows as you add more semesters, it may get bigger than 1MB and will be a heavy payload if listing notes in your UI.

Comment: thankyou for you replay but i had used only one array named = semester1 on notes colection and i has trouble on how to use query for semester array by arraycontain and i had used only on array to store multiple maps == model example :  [{ec321ec:valueec321ec},{ec5556:the value of }]

Comment: Even if you only have one semester, I'd recommend moving your maps from an array into a sub-collection